# Smartsheet API: How do I grab the values of all cells in a column?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I'm looking for a way to make an API call from inside a C# program that grabs all the values from one column on a sheet. In this case, the type of column is a DATE column.

Within the C# program, once I get the data back, I will be trying to find out what is the next upcoming date. I think I can handle this second part, but I am having trouble creating the API call in order to do so.

I've been looking at the documentation but I have very little experience with API calls so a lot of it doesn't make much sense to me yet. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just pointing me towards the proper resources I can use to figure it out on my own.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the info provided in the `smartsheet-api` tag you have added to your question. It has links to examples, sample projects, full API documentation, ... There is all you need. If you have a problem while implementing your needs, you can ask a specific question on where you get stuck, providing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the sample: https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet

This shows how to load a sheet, loop through the rows, and examine cell values in a specific column.